# Does Chrome suggest search terms according to the content in other tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, search

I've noticed that several times, when I start typing a search term into Chrome, the suggestions presented are terms already in one of the tabs I have open. For example, if I have "We didn't start the fire" playing in Grooveshark, putting `we didn't` into the search box immediately shows `we didn't start the fire` as the first suggestion. However, going to the Google homepage in incognito mode, `we didn't` gives me `we didn't dybak` as the first suggestion.

This isn't bulletproof, I suspect that the results only adapt to the content in the other tabs/windows if the term is already in the suggestion list.

The question is, does Chrome do this, and if so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not giving suggestions from other open tabs, it's giving suggestions from your search history via the omnibar.

When you use private browsing, all history/cookies/etc. is disabled and the only suggestions you get are from Google Autocomplete, where as in normal browsing the first autocomplete suggestions will be from things you previously typed (regardless if the tab is still open or if it is was in this browsing session) and *then* Google autocomplete.

Comment: I do know about the feature you refer to. However, the auto-complete results occasionally seem to be from things I've not typed into the omni-bar/Google box in recent times (like several months/years).
This seems to happen even if I've reached the tab in question to a link, without typing a search term. The behaviour is difficult to test, as once I've "accepted" a search suggestion, the autocomplete history, as you say, takes over.

Comment: not just search history, your previous browsing history on Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Chrome creates search suggestions using the content of webpages in your browsing history. The top answer at the time of my answering is completely incorrect.