# How does Google know about the content available in other tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search, google-search

I was going through a survey in playbuzz on Firefox. I reached a page where there were several difficult words (These words were not related to each other). I opened a new tab and was about to type the words one by one in the address bar to check their meaning. (My default search engine is Google and I have autosuggest turned on). The first word was suggested after I typed 3-4 characters. Now on the google search results page I started typing the next word and it was suggested after I entered the first character! Similar experience with next 3 words. How does this happen?

I understand that google reads my search history [Does Chrome suggest search terms according to the content in other tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/421140/does-chrome-suggest-search-terms-according-to-the-content-in-other-tabs)

But does it also read the content in my open tabs? If so, how do I control it?

Comment: Scientifically,Google uses a little bit some complex machine learning algorithms to analyze end- user **clickstream** which keeps on recording what a user clicks on while browsing the web.From there, prediction is based on logs behind scenes.For more indepth- description how this is done,you can join us here [**Artificial Intelligence**](http://ai.stackexchange.com/questions) .On the other hand,from the layman's view or understanding on here at super user community;you check in the browser settings and do some configurations there.

Comment: Analysing the clickstream is basically tracking my browsing history, right? It makes sense when I'm using chrome. But in this case I was using firefox! And those words were part of content in another tab! How google was able to read it is my question.

Comment: Hey,Google is beyond browsing you history!!!!....the thing is machine learning is what makes all words information to be universally accessible by everyone on earth.Firefox is just an open-source product...no billions invested in machine learning like the way Google does it!...even though your not using chrome...in terms of web technology....Google doesn't even blink at pages hosted on open web..Therefore,if your not in the AI field then still won't get what am saying..Lets just keep it that way.Regards.

Answer (score 1):

that answer is incorrect.
google does know the contents of other tabs.
just saw a face of an actress i recognise and her name also in 1 tab.
i wanted to check which shows and movies she played in so i opened a 2nd tab
i typed :imdb kath -google filled out the rest of her name-.
im curious what any of your suggestions is, im betting its gonna be a different name
since this is not even a top 10 actress beginning with kath.

Answer (score 0):

Google knows everything.

Seriously though, one plausible way is if enough people have done the same survey, and gone searching for the same words in the same order, google will recognise this.  So, you get a first hit when google gets enough letters to find a possible matching word and right then, google is looking for next word in a phrase beginning with that word combinations.

As soon as you type enough letters matching a popular search or phrase, google is ready to spit out the whole phrase for you.  So, google doesn't know the contents of words in one tab except in a coincidental sense.

Comment: Freaky coincidence!!